# Load the whole list in Variable Explorer in Spyder

Tags: numpy, spyder

I have a following problem: I wand to check the end of a long list (numpy array to be precise) in Variable Explorer in Spyder. But when I change sorting to the decreasing by index I will have only entries from my 1st screen. I have to scroll down to load them and only then I will see them.

For example I have 20,000 rows. If I will change sorting I will see only rows from 63. If I will scroll to the 200 row in normal order and then change it I will see only the rows only from 200.

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: what about a simple `print(arr[-10:])` to check the last 10 elements?

Comment: The main point of thus us to look what is going on during the script execution. I had found a way to avoid it by using pandas dataframe instead of numpy array. But I am still interested if Spyder Variable Explorer can be configured to preload the large arrays.